# How to suppress the "enumeral and non-enumeral type in conditional expression" warning in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I keep getting this warning from a third-party library (which I don't want to debug), so I'd really appreciate a way to suppress this specific warning.  Google failed me, so here I am.

Answer (score 1):

`-Wno-enum-compare` bypasses this warning.

[**See also**](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27975#c8)

Answer (score 1):

In gcc4.6 and later you can use pragma's to suppress specific warnings and do that suppression only to a specific block of code, i.e. :

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wno-enum-compare" 
// Code that causes warning goes here
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

The push/pop are used to preserve the diagnostic options that were in place before your code was processed.

This would be a much better approach than using `#pragma GCC system_header` to suppress all warnings. (Of course, in older gcc you may be "stuck" with the `#pragma GCC system_header` approach!)

Here's a nice reference on suppressing gcc warnings: http://www.dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/SuppressingGCCWarnings.html

This page also describes how to use `-fdiagnostics-show-option` to find out what option controls a particular warning.

Of course, it's generally far preferable to fix the root cause of all warnings than to suppress them! However, sometimes that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Won't the following flag get rid of that warning?

```
-Wno-enum-promotion
```

Comment: Nope.  In fact, gcc doesn't even seem to recognize this option.  Where did you find out about this option?  It's not listed on http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I couldn't find a way to disable this specific warning, I resorted to using gcc's #pragma system_header.  Basically, I wrapped the problematic header like this:

```
#if defined __GNUC__
#pragma GCC system_header
#elif defined __SUNPRO_CC
#pragma disable_warn
#elif defined _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(push, 1)
#endif

#include "foo.h"

#if defined __SUNPRO_CC
#pragma enable_warn
#elif defined _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

where foo.h was the problematic header.  Now I just include this fooWrapper.h and the problem goes away.  Note that this should work for some other compilers too (MSC and SUNPRO), but I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanx, this `#pragma GCC system_header` saved me from a bunch of non-sense warnings.